# Excel VBA: Application defined or Object defined error

Tags: vba, excel

I've written some code to look for sets of brackets in an excel file and white out the contents of the cells in between them. The code I have works for 26-27 lines before I get the error message.

Here is the code:

```
Sub macro()
Dim white As Long
Dim rowIndex As Long
Dim colIndex As Long
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim lastCol As Long

white = RGB(Red:=255, Green:=255, Blue:=255)

With ActiveSheet

lastRow = .Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
lastCol = .Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column

For rowIndex = 1 To lastRow
        For colIndex = 1 To lastCol
            If .Cells(rowIndex, colIndex).Text = "[" Then
                colIndex = colIndex + 1
                Do While .Cells(rowIndex, colIndex).Value <> "]"
                    .Cells(rowIndex, colIndex).Font.Color = white
                    colIndex = colIndex + 1
                Loop
            End If
        Next colIndex
Next rowIndex
End With
End Sub
```

The error occurs on this line:

```
Do While Cells(rowIndex, colIndex).Value <> "]"
```

I tried adding in:

```
With ActiveSheet
```

Along with . before each Cell command but it did not make a difference.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You probably should have a check that colIndex hasn't exceeded lastCol within the Do While loop. Otherwise if there is a "[" without a matching "]" then the loop won't stop where you want it to. A specific error number and message would make things easier to diagnose

Comment: Can you avoid the error with `Do While .Cells(rowIndex, colIndex).Value <> "]" And colIndex <= lastCol`? If this is the case then `]` is never found and you've tried to run off the right side of the worksheet. Perhaps there is a leading/trailing space with `] ` or ` ]`. That will produce the 1004 error.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, the error goes away when I add that last bit in. I didn't think I needed a boundary check because there would always be a matching ]. Turns out the error was due to a " ]" instead of a "]". That extra space threw the error.

Comment: Do you want to speed it up? Using a pair of [MATCH functions](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) is much faster than looping through the cells and you can wildcard the search.

Comment: @Jeeped doooo eeeet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If one of the cells containing `[` or `]` may have rogue leading trailing spaces/non-breaking spaces then a wildcard comparison should be made. Additionally, the worksheet's [MATCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) can locate the bracketing cells with a wildcard search more efficiently than looping through each cell row-by-row.

```
Sub hide_cell_values()
    Dim whiteOut As String   '<~~ using alternate method .NumberFormat ;;;
    Dim rw As Long, n As Long, f As Long, l As Long

    whiteOut = ";;;"    'custom cell number format to show nothing in cell

    With ActiveSheet
        'process row by row in the .UsedRange
        With .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell))
            For rw = 1 To .Rows.Count
                ' check for existance of matching pairs
                If Not IsError(Application.Match("*[*", .Rows(rw), 0)) And _
                               Application.CountIf(.Rows(rw), "*[*") = _
                               Application.CountIf(.Rows(rw), "*]*") Then
                    ' [ and ] pairs exist and match in row.
                    f = 0: l = 0
                    For n = 1 To Application.CountIf(.Rows(rw), "*[*")
                        'this looks complicated but it just references the cells between [ & ]
                        f = Application.Match("*[*", .Rows(rw).Cells.Offset(0, l), 0) + l + 1
                        ' last safety check to ensure that [ comes before ]
                        If Not IsError(Application.Match("*]*", .Rows(rw).Cells.Offset(0, f), 0)) Then
                            l = Application.Match("*]*", .Rows(rw).Cells.Offset(0, f), 0) + f - 1
                            With .Range(.Cells(rw, f), .Cells(rw, l))
                                'this is a better method of not displaying text in a cell
                                .NumberFormat = whiteOut    '<~~ e.g. ;;;
                                'the old method of white-text-on-white-background (not reliable as .Interior.Color can change)
                                '.Font.Color = vbWhite
                            End With
                        End If
                    Next n
                Else
                    ' [ and ] pairs do not match or do not exist in row. do nothing.
                End If
            Next rw
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

I have opted for a custom cell number format of `;;;` rather than altering the font color to `RGB(255, 255, 255)` (see footnote ¹). A [Range.NumberFormat property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196401.aspx) of three semi-colons in a row simply shows nothing; a white font's apparent visibility is subject to the cell's [Range.Interior.Color property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840499.aspx), the [worksheet backgroun](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-or-remove-a-sheet-background-3577a762-8450-4556-96a2-cc265abc00a8) or even the 'Window background' in the computer's system settings.

[image: Hiding cell contents before sub]
    <sup>Before running sub</sup>

[image: Hiding cell contents after sub]
    <sup>After running sub</sup>

In the *before* and *after* images above, you can see that D2 retains its [Range.Value property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195193.aspx) (visible in the formula bar) while showig nothing on the worksheet. Note: cell values can still be copied from a cell displaying nothing but that is a caveat of using the `vbWhite` method as well.

---

¹ <sub>There are predefined RGB long type constants for the basic VBA pallette. `RGB(255, 255, 255)` is equal to `vbWhite`. Full list available at [Color Constants](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278810.aspx).</sub>

Comment: <3 So this may be more efficient but code is harder to read/understand (at least for me XD). Regardless, thank you, gonna study it...